# Javascript: Do complex value references affect execution speed?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm writing an animation loop and so trying to optimize for speed.  This involves sacrificing a lot of readablity, but I'm wondering if at some point it becomes counter-productive.  For example, I might start with something like this:

```
var Animation = Animations[Current_Animation];
var Sequence = Animation.Sequences[Current_Sequence];
var Action = Sequence.Actions[Current_Action];
if (Action.Repeat_Count != Action.Repeat_End) Sequence.Index--;
```

But when I remove the extraneous variables for optimization, it comes out with truly massive references:

```
if (Animations[Current_Animation].Sequences[Current_Sequence].Actions
 [Animations[Current_Animation].Sequences[Current_Sequence].Index].Repeat_Count
 != Animations[Current_Animation].Sequences[Current_Sequence].Actions
 [Animations[Current_Animation].Sequences[Current_Sequence].Index].Repeat_End)
 Animations[Current_Animation].Sequences[Current_Sequence].Index--;
```

My loop is now full of such monstrosities.  So I'm wondering if the interpreter having to stop and sort all of that out might actually be slower than using the placeholders.  Or does it automagically know what it all means without using any extra CPU?

Thanks!

Comment: Modern browser probably improved a lot in this regard but avoiding unnecessary property lookups is still a good thing. Besides, it just feels wrong to repeat `Animations[Current_Animation].Sequences[Current_Sequence]` over and over again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shorter code is more readable ***and*** faster on any JS engine I've used, not to mention if this is client side JS the download time will be shorter for less having less bytes!

However you should be using the `var` keyword so that all your variables aren't in the global scope. I'm sure that you have no reason for `Animation`, `Sequence`, and `Action` to be globals in the above code, since they are really just meant to be temporary variables, but since they are not explicitly declared as local to the current function scope, they are automatically global.

```
var Animation = Animations[Current_Animation];
var Sequence = Animation.Sequences[Current_Sequence];
var Action = Sequence.Actions[Current_Action];
if (Action.Repeat_Count != Action.Repeat_End) Sequence.Index--;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per a [talk given at SXSW (slide 40)](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=0Ac0YlG9vMA2LZHE1MnpycF8yMGZ6ZnZxa2hy&pli=1) this week, it is [not impacting on performance](http://jsperf.com/scriptjunkie-premature-5) in any significant way in practically any widely deployed browser.

The version which uses references (the first code sample), however, is MUCH easier to read, IMO. As noted by *PaulP.R.O.* it would need proper scope control via `var`, but it is (admittedly subjectively) better code.